# Is there always a toric isomorphism between isomorphic toric varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

Suppose two toric varieties are isomorphic as abstract varieties. Does it follow that there exists a toric isomorphism between them?

---

Edit: the comments below lead me to believe that I'm using the terms "toric variety" and "toric morphism" in a non-standard way, so let me clarify. Here are the definitions I have in mind.

**Definition:** A *toric variety* is a normal variety $X$ together with (1) a dense open subvariety $T\subseteq X$, and (2) a group structure on $T$ making it a torus, such that the action of $T$ on itself extends to an action on $X$. (Note: I *do not* include the data of an isomorphism between $T$ and $\mathbb G_m^{\dim X}$, but only require that such an isomorphism exists.)

**Definition:** If $(X,T_X)$ and $(Y,T_Y)$ are toric varieties (group structures on $T_X$ and $T_Y$ implicit), a *toric morphism* between them is a morphism $f:X\to Y$ which restricts to a group homomorphism $f|_{T_X}:T_X\to T_Y$.

Comment: I think there is a trivial class of counterexamples, take a given action and compose it with an automorphism of the torus. This gives a new toric variety in general different, as what is usually meant by "toric variety", from the original. Taking that into account Dave's remark below gives indeed an equivalent formulation.

Comment: Thanks for point this out, Torsten -- for a very easy example, take a fan and its negative!  (Corresponding to $t \mapsto t^{-1}$.)  So until you factor out automorphisms of $T$, even the affine line has multiple toric structures.

Comment: I don't follow. The question does not ask if every isomorphism is toric (of course not), just if a toric isomorphism exists. For example, you could translate the usual toric structure on $\mathbb A^1$ so that the origin is in the big torus orbit and 1 is torus-invariant. This would be a different toric structure on $\mathbb A^1$, and $id_{\mathbb A^1}$ is a non-toric isomorphism. But there also exists a toric isomorphism: the translation we used to define the toric structure.

Comment: Anton, here is another way of thinking of it for $\mathbb{A}^1$: the two structures given by the standard action and by composing with $t\mapsto t^{-1}$ are two *different* equivariant line bundles on a point.  (Their Chern classes are different, so there can be no equivariant isomorphism between them.)

Comment: @Dave: I still don't follow. It sounds to me like you're saying that there is no way to extend the automorphism of the torus $t\mapsto t^{-1}$ to an automorphism of $\mathbb A^1$. I agree with that, but I don't see how it is relevant. For any two toric structures you put on $\mathbb A^1$, there is an automorphism of $\mathbb A^1$ sending one to the other. A toric structure does not include a choice of isomorphism between the torus and $\mathbb G_m^n$.

Comment: Let me ask a (hopefully) clarifying question: in what way does the identity map on $\mathbb A^1$ fail to be a toric isomorphism between the different toric structures you propose?

Comment: Anton, now that you've included the definition of "toric morphism" you're using, I agree.  Another way to interpret the term is as a synonym for "$T$-equivariant map", and this is how the examples Torsten mentioned arise.  (The confusion does not come from choosing a basis of $T$, but rather from whether you're allowed to take equivariant maps over an *arbitrary* group homomorphism $T\to T'$, rather than just the identity.)  Now the question is equivalent to the reformulation in my answer.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for confirming that the confusion came from the terminology.

Answer (score 14):

This is a partial answer.  Let $X$ be the given abstract variety.  I think the question is equivalent to asking whether all maximal tori in the group $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ are conjugate.  When $X$ is complete, this is a linear algebraic group, so all maximal tori are conjugate, and the answer is affirmative.  (See Cox's famous paper on the homogeneous coordinate ring.)

If $X$ is not complete, the automorphism group may of course be infinite-dimensional, but perhaps you can argue by compactifying.

Comment: Can you explain why the question is equivalent to showing that maximal tori of $Aut(X)$ are conjugate? If $T\subseteq X$ is a torus whose action on itself extends to an action on $X$, then we get $T\subseteq Aut(X)$, but is it necessarily a maximal torus?

Comment: Let $T$ be the torus coming from the toric variety, and let $T \subseteq T'$ be tori in the automorphism group. Then $T'$ is abelian and contains $T$. So the $T'$ action commutes with the $T$ action. But it is standard (meaning that I can't remember a reference) that the group of automorphisms of a toric variety commuting with the torus action is precisely the torus action.

Comment: Thanks David. Such an automorphism must respect the open subset $T\subseteq X$, so after adjusting it by the action of $T$, we may assume it sends the identity element to itself. Now since it commutes with the action of $T$, it must fix all of $T$, so it must fix all of $X$ (since $X$ is separated).

Comment: David and Anton, that seems like the best proof of this fact.  (I don't know anything about conjugacy of tori in wild beasts like $Aut(X)$ in general though -- do you?)

Comment: Is there any hope in general with this line of though? $Aut(\mathbb A^n)$ is pretty wild... (literally :) )

Comment: Just to make sure I'm on the same page, the question right now is whether every automorphism (which is not toric) of a toric variety $X$ is induced by an automorphism of *some* toric compactification, right?

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, and that the proof will use Cox rings. However, I haven't been able to find references for all the facts about Cox rings I want, so I'll leave this as CW and hope someone else fills in the gaps.

Let $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$ be two fans, and $X$ and $X'$ the corresponding toric varieties, with $X \cong X'$. For simplicity, I'll assume that the unit groups of $X$ and $X'$ are both trivial (i.e. equal to $k^*$). This is equivalent to assuming that $\Sigma$ (respectively $\Sigma'$) is not contained in a hyperplane.

Let $H$ be the class group of $X$ (Weil divisors modulo principal divisors). Let $G$ be the character group $\mathrm{Hom}(H, \mathbb{G}_m)$. Cox's construction gives: A variety $Y$; an action of $G$ on $Y$; a $G$-invariant open subspace $U$; and a map $U \to X$ which makes $X$ into the categorical quotient $U/G$. This is sometimes called the *universal torsor* of $X$, although it is only a torsor when $X$ is smooth (earlier false statement corrected).

To help get you oriented, if $X = \mathbb{P}^2$, then $H = \mathbb{Z}$, $G = \mathbb{G}_m$, $Y= \mathbb{A}^3$ and $U$ is the complement of the origin in $Y$.

---

There are two ways to think about this construction. The one I understand well is the one from [Cox's original paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9210008). Let $\rho_1$, ..., $\rho_N$ be the rays of $\Sigma$. Let $Y = \mathbb{A}^N$. Each ray represents a class in $H$, and hence a character of $G$. Let $G$ acts on the $i$-th coordinate of $Y$ by the character of $G$ corresponding to $\rho_i$. Let $(y_1, \ldots, y_N)$ be a point of $Y$. Let $i_1$, \ldots, $i_k$ be the coordiantes for which $y_{i_j} =0$. Then $(y_1, \ldots, y_N)$ is in $U$ if and only if there is a cone of $\Sigma$ containing the rays $\rho_{i_1}$, ..., $\rho_{i_k}$. I'll cite you to Cox's paper for the map $U \to X$.

---

That contsruction is very explicit, but it uses the fan. There is a more abstract construction, which I don't understand as well, which works for any normal variety and does not use the torus action. Specifically, for every $h \in H$, choose a specific Weil divisor $D(h)$ representing $h$. For any $h_1$ and $h_2$, choose a rational function $u(h_1, h_2)$ with divisor $D(h_1+h_2) - D(h_1) - D(h_2)$, subject to conditions to be named later.

Define the ring 
$$R := \bigoplus_{h \in H} H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(D(h)))$$
with multiplication $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(D(h_1))) \times H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(D(h_2))) \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(D(h_1 + h_2)))$ given by $f_1 \times f_2 = f_1 f_2 u(h_1, h_2)$. My understanding is that (1) it is always possible to choose the $u$'s such that this is a commutative and associative ring and (2) $R$ is independent of these choices, up to nonunique isomorphism. However, you should check these claims before using them.

We set $Y = \mathrm{Spec} \ R$. This comes with an obvious action of $G$, where $G$ acts on $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(D(h)))$ by the character $h$. I am not sure how to define $U$ or the map $U \to X$, but I think there is a way. Note that none of this uses the torus action.

---

Now, let $(\Sigma, X)$ and $(\Sigma', X')$ be as above, and let $(Y, G, U, U \to X)$ and $(Y', G', U', U' \to X')$ be the results of the above constructions. If I am right that the Cox construction is sufficiently natural, then there should be isomorphisms $Y \cong Y'$ and $U \cong U'$, making the obvious diagrams commute. (Note that the construction of $G$ is intrinsic, so we definitely have $G \cong G'$.)

From the first description of the Cox ring, we see that $Y \cong Y' \cong \mathbb{A}^N$, so that $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$ both have $N$ rays.

A priori, we have $Y \cong Y'$ as $G$-varieties, and we know that each of $Y$ and $Y'$ can be identified with $\mathbb{A}^N$ so that the $G$-action becomes linear. My next claim is that the two representations of $G$ are isomorphic; i.e., we can arrange that the composition $\mathbb{A}^n \cong Y \cong Y' \cong \mathbb{A}^N$ is linear. Proof: Find a point $y$ in $Y$, fixed by the $G$-action. There is at least one such point, because the origin is fixed. Let $\phi: Y \to Y'$ be any $G$-equivariant isomorphism. Then the $G$-action on $Y$ is isomorphic to the $G$-action on the tangent space $T_y Y$, and the $G$-action on $Y'$ is isomorphic to the $G$-action on $T_{\phi(y)} Y'$. But the differential $D \phi : T_y Y \to T_{\phi(y)} Y'$ gives a linear isomorphism between the tangent spaces. Transporting structure, we have the claim.

So, $G$ acts on $Y$ and on $Y'$ by the same characters. This means that $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$ have the same rays. Now, looking at the combinatorics of $Y \setminus U$ and $Y' \setminus U'$, you should be able to read off the corresponding fans.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if you are still interested in a reference for this, but I recently found that this is proved in section 4 of ["Lifting of morphisms to quotient presentations"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209406) by F. Berchtold. The proof uses the Cox construction and it seems to me that the argument is the one that David suggested above, but I am not done reading the paper. I hope this helps.